# Excel Formula: If cell contains "...", then insert "..." into adjacent cell, based on acronym rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of item names based on their SKUs, for example:

- SKU = ITEM NAME
- TS =  Men’s Tee
- PP = Men’s Pants
- PT = Plain Pocket Tee
- MS = Men's Shorts
- B = Boxer
- BB = Boxer Briefs

How do I generate Item Names in Column B, based on the sku in Column C?
Currently, I am using

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("...",C1)), "...")

[image: visual example]

This formula works, but manually entering "B", and "Boxer" in each cell is tedious. How do I automate this?

I found something similar [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/how-to-quot-if-cell-contains-specific-text-then-return-specific/m-p/69802#M8651), but I don't know how to reverse engineer it.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a bit of sample data with a visual for expected result

Comment: Thanks, I updated with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a **structured reference table** called `SKU` as below:

[image: SKU Table]

Please note, you must sort the `Code` column in alphabetic order (A-Z).

Suppose you want to return the product name in Column B based on the SKU code in Column C, in Cell `B2`, enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SKU[Code],C2)),SKU[Name])
```

See below demonstration:

[image: Result Table]

The key step here is to set up a lookup table first, then you will be able to look up the product name based on the SKU code (use **SEARCH** function).

================ Added Solution ================

To fix the issue of having product code within another product code and not returning the correct product name, please use the following formula instead (assuming all your product codes are consist of letters only without any numbers):

```
=LOOKUP(LEFT(C2,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-1,C2),LEN(C2)))-1),SKU[Code],SKU[Name])
```

The key of the above formula is to find where the product code ends within each text string, for example, the product codes ends on the second character of this text string `PP416`, and the following formula will return number `2` to indicate that:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-1,C2),LEN(C2))
```

Then you can use the **LEFT** function to extract the product code out of the text string, and use the **LOOKUP** function to return the corresponding product description.

[image: Second solution]

If your version of Excel has **XLOOKUP** function, I suggest you replace **LOOKUP** with **XLOOKUP**, the rest of the formula does not change. You can google how to use **XLOOKUP** as it is more powerful than **LOOKUP**.

Let me know if you have any question :)

Comment: Thank you very much. 
This is a fantastic solution.
I am running into some errors, however. Only some of the Names are working The rest show #NA. (see attached image, I've double clicked inside a cell that wasn't working). 
This is probably a data entry error on my part.

https://imgur.com/UmAYjk2

Comment: I found the issue.
There were spaces in the CODE column of my SKU table.
Thanks again @Terry W

Comment: @raggedmane glad it worked for you. Please mark my answer as the accepted answer (by clicking the tick sign) if you think my solution has worked for you. Tks.

Comment: One issue I am having, are codes which share letters (such as BNS and NS,) don't show the correct Name. No BNS Names are currently generated. Is there a way to fix this? 

Gracias. @Terry W

Comment: See comment above^
[Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11768364/terry-w)

Comment: @raggedmane please see the edited answer :)

Comment: That worked excellently. Thank you again @Terry W

Comment: Can I use this formula to to generate Item Descriptions, except this time they are based on numbers [see here](https://imgur.com/a/i93QGsh). I've tried, but I can't get it to work.
Thanks again, [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11768364/terry-w)

Comment: @raggedmane I suggest you either modify your question or ask a new one so we can see what you have tried and then know how to help you out.

Comment: Here is a [graphic](https://imgur.com/a/V8Z7HRc) of what I want to achieve, [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11768364/terry-w).